# How to create two columns inside the recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to do the same design in the picture before you

[image]

I've created most things except for the contents inside `RecyclerView`
I want to create two columns inside `RecyclerView` such as in the picture
So that a column in the right side is smaller than the left column

Comment: This question reads more like a scope for a paid job than a programming question. I'd recommend at least making an attempt and asking a specific question when you get stuck. Flagging to close as too broad.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a linear layout to each item of the recycler view and inflate them with your array of objects. Then each linear layout is then split into two parts. You could also achieve this with a relative layout inside the recycler view.

You might want to look at androids weight and weightsum properties.

Answer (score -1):

so basically what you have to do is to change your layout and make each item of the recyclerview a cardView

in addition inside this cardview create a linearLayout with a specific weight for example weightSum of 2

and each Text give it a weight of 1 and it will be automatically divded into 2

it's all based on weight Sum and a linear layout